# What is "Expression must have class type"

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory, member

I used std::malloc() on a pointer which is a member of an object. And in a method, it threw an error.

```
[...]
class SomeClass
{
  public:
    void method()
    {
      this.ptr = std::malloc(4);
    }

    int* ptr;
}
[...]
```

And it throws an error saying:

```
Error: Expression must have class type
```

What is the problem in my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because `this` is a pointer and to try to access it using `.`.
Moreover malloc returns a `void*` so you must cast

Try writing this instead :

```
this->ptr = static_cast<int *>(std::malloc(4));
```

Comment: In C++ you need to cast the malloc on the right hand side.

Comment: Yes, edited the post to take that into account

Comment: Yeah I just learned it from a sketchy website in the dark corners of the internet, apparently this isn't an object like in other languages... 

Comment: @TheSmolCodar usually it would be called `self` in those, except for java. They are _references_ to object.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two problems:

First, it should be `this->ptr` instead of the dot.

Second, you must cast the result of `malloc()` to the pointer type you want. For example, `this->ptr = static_cast<int *>(malloc(4));`

There are some other problems with your code too.

1. You must `free()` the pointer you've allocated. If you `malloc` it, you'd have to `free` it somewhere too.
2. You are assuming that an `int` is four bytes in size. This is not correct. You should use `sizeof(int)`. Or at least add a `static_assert(sizeof(int) == 4);` if you have to assume it.
3. If you use `new` to allocate memory (instead of `malloc`) like this: `this->ptr = new int;`, you simultaneously get rid of two of the problems above. You won't need to cast the returned pointer, and you won't assume the size of an int to always be 4.
4. If you use `new`, don't forget to `delete` the pointer (instead of `free`.)
5. Always initialize your pointers to `nullptr`, and remember to set them to `nullptr` after freeing/deleting them too. This helps you avoid some common silent bugs.

Stylistically, you can avoid using a raw pointer and instead use something like a `std::unique_ptr<int>`. But that's up to you.

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree on (5): in my opinion doing that masks poorly written code which is bound to have other control flow issues.

Comment: Yes, and having pointers set to either the address of a valid object or a `nullptr` causes your program to crash if you try and access it outside of its valid lifetime, hence helping you to diagnose those "control flow" issues. What's the alternative? Just pointing to some old and deallocated memory that might or might not have another object in it and silently reading and writing those bytes?!

Answer (score 1):

C++ is not Java. You need `this->` rather than `this.`.

Although in your case you can write, simply, `ptr = (int*)std::malloc(4)` since the `this->` is implicit.

Better still, write `ptr = new int;` because then you're not making assumptions about `sizeof(int)`. Don't forget you need a `delete int;` somewhere too and you need to worry about assignment operators, copy constructors, and the destructor.

Even better then to use `std::unique_ptr<int>` or `std::shared_ptr<int>` for the `ptr` type, so you don't need to worry about the `delete`.

Even better perhaps, use `int` as the member type, if the requirements allow.

Answer (score 0):

`this.ptr` is not valid!

`this` is a pointer and the members must be accessed with the pointer operator:

```
this->ptr = static_cast<int *>(std::malloc(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

What strange compiler gives error message like this?

It complains about left side of dot operator in `this.ptr` expression.  Dot operator assumes that left side should be a class-type, while `this` is a pointer to a class-type. You have to use `->`.

Secondly, malloc returns `void*`, you have to convert it. Avoid the hassle and use `new int` unless you really must to use malloc.

Comment: Also maybe he should not use raw pointers at all, but that is depending on the use-case and what he tries to achieve

Comment: @RoQuOTriX True. At end of writing answer, I remembered what compiler could gave such error text: Turbo-C++. Architecturally IDE was limited to one line per error so programmer had to decode those as some kind of cipher. So I didn't bother to suggest it.